# How to access the package com.google.appengine.api.datastore from the front end code

Tags: java, android, eclipse, google-app-engine

Eclipse, GoogleAppEngine, Trying to use the method

```
KeyFactory.keyToString(Key)
```

in my client side logic but I need to import

```
import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Key;
import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.KeyFactory;
```

but I I'm getting the "cannot be resolved error"

Additional Info:
It works with in the backend code

Installed additional google api: google cloud datastore api

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need a Key object in the client code? You cannot use it in the client anyway. Pass a String representation of a key (or, event better, a Long id or String name for your entity) between your backend and your client, and convert it to a Key on the server side when you are ready to use it.

Comment: I'm storing the string rep in a table on the local db, and I can't pass in the string rep because I'm using the list method generated in the Endpoint class which returns a CollectionResponse object

Comment: OK, refactor your code. You cannot use App Engine classes on the client.